# Can React.createRef() be created dynamically from an array of state objects?

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of styled radio buttons fixed inside the sidebar that, when clicked, scroll a corresponding component from the main area into view.
Both the radio buttons list and the components inside the main area are mapped from the state array called usedComponents that contains objects of component properties and ids. Let's say the array contains 10 objects and each object looks something like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  group: "header",
  componentType: "headerLogo",
  componentName: "Header 01",
  //...rest of the component properties
}
```

In order to achieve scroll into view on radio button click I had to create references to components inside the constructor. I manually created references for each component contained inside usedComponents state array and tied them to componentType like this:

```
this.headerLogo = React.createRef();
this.headerLogoNavigation = React.createRef();
//...etc.
```

I then passed the reference to each corresponding component and in my selectComponentHandler I set scrollIntoView to call the radio button id which corresponds to the main area component reference.
The selectComponentHandler looks like this:

```
selectComponentHandler = e => {
  const value = Number(e.target.value);
  const id = e.target.id; //returns componentType. For example "headerLogo"
  this.setState(prevState => {
    let selected = prevState.usedComponents
      .filter(item => item.id === value)
      .shift();
    let unSelected = prevState.usedComponents
      .filter(item => item.selected === true)
      .shift();
    if (unSelected) {
      unSelected.selected = false;
    }
    selected.selected = true;
    return { unSelected, selected };
  });
  this[id].current.scrollIntoView({ block: "start", behavior: "smooth" });
};
```

However, I'm using react-beautiful-dnd in order to be able to add new components  by dragging them to the main area, and whenever I add the new component of the type that is already contained inside the usedComponents array, it has the same reference as the old component of the same type. This makes the scrollIntoView always scroll to the component of the same type that is first in line, no matter which one I select. 
Is there a way to create references dynamically for all the components inside the usedComponents array, by perhaps mapping them, and update them whenever a new component is inserted. Maybe tie them to ids?

Edit:
I tried mapping references inside the constructor like this:

```
this.state.usedComponents.map(component => {
  const id = component.id.toString();
  return (this[id] = React.createRef());
});
```

It works for the components that are already inside the used Components array, however I still don't know how to update the references when the new object is inserted into the usedComponents array via drag and drop. Newly inserted components basically don't have references.

Comment: yes, you should probably tie to id's or whatever is unique to know what to scroll to.

Comment: I just updated my question. I managed to map references to constructor and I tied them to ids, but I still don't know how to update them after the new component is added to usedComponents array. Do you perhaps have an idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: how many components would you be creating refs for? I would probably avoid using refs if its a lot. Instead you can apply an `id` on each element `<div id={component.id}` and then you can just get that element with a dom query. `document.getElementById(component.id).scrollIntoView()` or whatever. Probably dont need React to do this particular mapping / operation

Comment: Great!! I'll write up an answer then so we can close this question out :) glad that helps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like I was mentioning in the comments, I wouldn't go the route of dynamic refs. The scope / size of these refs could grow large and there is a much better way to handle this. Just use the DOM.

When rendering you can just put the components ID on your html element that you want to scroll to

```
<div id={component.id}> ... </div>
```

And then when you want to scroll to that element just query the DOM for that element and scroll to it

```
const elemToScrollTo = document.getElementById(component.id)
if (!!elemToScrollTo) {
  elemToScrollTo.scrollIntoView()
}
```